# C# / WPF - Accessing a listbox created in XAML through *.CS file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, listbox

I made a ListBox through the xaml file.  When the user enters something in a textbox, it'll add a textbox and a button to the Row of the ListBox.

I want that button to be a "delete-it's-own-row button".  But when I try to do it, it won't let me access the ListBox because "Cannot access non-static field in a static context".

```
public class GenericRowItem
    {
        private StackPanel _genericStackPanel = new StackPanel();
        private TextBox _genericTextBoxImage = new TextBox();
        private TextBox _genericTextBoxText = new TextBox();
        private CheckBox _genericCheckBox = new CheckBox();
        private Button _genericButton = new Button();

        public GenericRowItem(String text)
        {
            _genericButton.Content = "X";
            _genericButton.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            _genericButton.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            _genericButton.Width = 25;
            _genericButton.Height = 25;
            _genericButton.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            _genericButton.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            _genericButton.Click += GenericListBox.Items.... <--- THIS DOESN'T WORK, IT WONT ACCESS GENERICLISTBOX                
        }

        public StackPanel GetStackPanel()
        {
            return _genericStackPanel;
        }
    }
```

my xaml code:

```
<ListBox Name ="GenericListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="195" Margin="25,345,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="650" FontFamily="Courier New" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            </ListBox>
```

Comment: Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code. What you need is to define an `ItemTemplate` to the ListBox.

Comment: okay i'll look into that.  sorry new to C# and WPF. just got thrown into this at work. if someone can help me out with how to change the xaml though that'd be so helpful.

Comment: Basically in WPF, you need to learn to manipulate the data and let the UI automatically update through templates and bindings. Working with the UI directly is much more difficult and is basically not the intent of WPF. For example, I add an item to a list. The control is bound to the list automatically creates the Controls from the template for the type of item and binds the properties in those controls to the properties of the item. In the XAML I bind the ListBox to the List and define the Template that specifies which controls are used to display an item

Comment: k will look into that... a little bit confused about the latter half of your message Alan.. but i guess i gotta research more